# Ununderstandable function-like macro in C

Tags: c, function, macros

i have this c macro code :

```
#define d(x, y, z) (    \
      x += z,               \
      y += x,               \
      x += y                \

)
```

I have several questions :

1. Does this macro function return something ? (e.g. return x, y, or z)
   or is it just add the parameter variable with itself ? (which is
   useless, i think).
2. What does the `\` means ?
3. Why does the original coder use `comma-operator` after each operation ? Why not just use `;` instead of `,` ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: BTW, this code is terrible and will add lots bugs if you want to use it.

Comment: try guess the result of `int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4;` and `int a=1;int b=d(1,a,3);`?

Comment: "Understandable macro in C" is something of an oxymoron.

Comment: The use of the comma operator and surrounding `()` makes the whole thing a simple statement, meaning the macro can, eg, be placed after an `if` (sans `{}`) without fear that it will result in a broken `if` clause.  Using `{}` would have worked about as well, but I'm vaguely recalling that there's some scenario where the `()` is better.

Comment: Yeah, as @BryanChen points out, it's generally not a good idea for a macro to modify one of its operands, and especially not wise for it to modify several.  Confusion can result that will make the comma issue seem like child's play in comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost #define is a Preprocessor Directive, which means when the source code/c code is complied the #define replaces LHS with RHS - meaning whereever the d(x,y,z) is used will be replaced with the equation given

for example the below c code will print - modified a = 9, b=8, c=9

```
#define d(x,y,z) \
    x+=1,       \
    y+=2,       \
    z+=3       


#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    unsigned int a,b,c;
    a=5;
    b=6;
    c=7;

    printf("modified a = %d, b=%d, c=%d \n",d(a,b,c));    
}
```

basically what happened here is d(a,b,c) - is replaced with a+=1,b+=2,c+=3

1. The meaning of \ is that the pre-processor directive continues in the next line.
2. As for as the comma-operator is concerned we need to look at source code to see where exactly it is used. as you can see in the above code the comma operator actually separates all the three variables and is able to print properly - if in case i replace comma with any other operator we will get compilation error.

Hope this answers your questions :)

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 5):

> Does this macro function return something ? (e.g. return x, y, or z) or is it just add the parameter variable with itself ? (which is useless, i think).

It modifies the value of the variables. The "return" value is the final value of `x`.

> What does the \ means ?

When placed last on a line, it negates the newline so that the macro definition can span more than one line.

> Why does the original coder use comma-operator after each operation? Why not just use `;` instead of `, ?

Macros replace text. Consider the following code:

```
int x=1, y=2, z=3, f;
f = 3 * (d(x,y,z));
```

If the macro uses comma, the code becomes:

```
int x=1, y=2, z=3, f;
f = 3 * (x+=z, y+=x, x+=y);  // Evaluates to 3 * (the final value of x)
```

If the macro uses semicolon, the code becomes:

```
int x=1, y=2, z=3, f;
f = 3 * (x+=z; y+=x; x+=y);  // Syntax error!!!
```

Comment: the syntax error can be avoid by add `{}` inside the macro. so it become something like `({x+=z; y+=x; x+=y})`

Comment: @BryanChen You forgot the last semicolon `({x+=z; y+=x; x+=y;})`

Comment: @BryanChen: You can use compound statements in expressions?

Comment: @undur_gongor it is [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

Comment: @Bryan I try to stick to portable constructs/advice unless the question is about non-standard behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

1) The macro does not return anything itself. It is just a dumb piece of code substituted literally by the preprocessor wherever it encounters it. It can be any kind of text.

2) \ is used for letting the preprocessor know that the current macro also expands over the next line. (multi-line macro)

3) I cannot make any assumption about the original coder's intentions. However by using the comma operator in there the whole macro becomes a C language expression. For example running something like this works (it wouldn't if semicolons were in there):

```
int a = 0;

int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = 3;

a = d(x, y, z);

printf("a = %d\n", a);
printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("y = %d\n", y);
printf("z = %d\n", z);
```

and prints:

```
a = 10
x = 10
y = 6
z = 3
```

Comment: @BryanChen - Without consulting the lawyers I'd define it as something that returns an assignable value, and a `(,,)` expression will return the value of the last inner expression -- in this case the value of `x`.

Comment: Yeah, it's important, when splitting hairs is necessary, to understand that the macro itself returns only a character string, and it returns that to the compiler which then embeds it in the source code in place of the macro invocation.  Whatever "value" the macro may "return" at the program level is exactly the same value that would be returned by "hard coding" the equivalent source code sequence in the main program source.